# Laravel getting array as strings in notification

Tags: php, laravel

I have project which has tags and I want to return those tags as hashtags in my notification content but I get `Array to string conversion`

```
public function toTelegram($notifiable)
{
  $tags = [];
  foreach($project->tags as $tag) {
    $tags[] = '#'.$tag->title;
  }

  return TelegramFile::create()
    ->to(xxxxxx)
    ->content("New\n\n".$this->project->title."\n\n $tags");
}
```

**Question**

How can I get my notification content as `new test project #tag1 #tag2 #tag3` ?

Comment: Use `implode(' ', $tags)` instead of just $tags

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya have tried that, same error happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I've added new line to my code and it fixed the issue

```
$tags = [];
//....

$hashtags = implode(',', $tags);

return TelegramFile::create()
  ->to(xxxxxxxx)
  ->content("New\n\n".$this->project->title."\n\n $hashtags")
```